# IsDaylightSavingTime is triggered at 1:00 instead of 2:00

Tags: c#, dst

I'm simply trying to determine if a given date falls within Daylight Saving Time. In 2017, Nov 5th at 2:00 AM should be the trigger.

- If my input is 11/5/17 00:00:00 the output is true for DST
- If my input is 11/5/17 01:00:00 the output is false for DST

I would have expected 1 AM to be true, and 2 AM to be false for DST

here is my code

```
var dateTime = new DateTime(2017,11,5,0,0,0);
var targetTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time");

if (targetTimeZone.IsDaylightSavingTime(dateTime)) {
    Console.WriteLine("Daylight Saving Time");
}
```

Comment: Consider that 1am happens twice.  You need to tell it which one it is when you create your `DateTime`.

Comment: Interesting, how does one go about doing that?

Comment: `IsAmbiguousTime` will help you *reason* about this more clearly but if all you have is a `DateTime` that isn't `Utc` there's not much that can be done about it - nobody has any way of knowing which point in time that `Local` datetime value represented.

Comment: Use TimeZoneInfo.IsAmbiguousTime() to ensure you should not be asking this question.

Comment: What about if you store somewhere XML, DB, etc. the previous DST in order to know and check later.

Comment: Stuff like this is *precisely* why NodaTime was created.  You might consider looking into it.

Comment: Consider using UTC time in your database and change it on display to the user to the local time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.isdaylightsavingtime?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_TimeZoneInfo_IsDaylightSavingTime_System_DateTime_) (in the Remarks section):

> If the `dateTime` parameter specifies an ambiguous time in the current object's time zone, the `TimeZoneInfo.IsDaylightSavingTime` method interprets `dateTime` as standard time and returns false if its `Kind` property is `DateTimeKind.Local` or `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`. If the Kind property is `DateTimeKind.Utc`, this method will select the correct ambiguous time and indicate whether it is a daylight saving time.

It then goes on to explain `IsAmbiguousTime`, and a long example showing how to use them that very closely matches the scenario you described.

Also note that the overload for `IsDaylightSavingTime` that accepts a `DateTimeOffset` parameter does not have this issue because values cannot be ambiguous when an offset is present - similar to when Kind is UTC.